# How to get position of item selecte in gridview, or detect release of key with onItemClick?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I must be able to detect the press and release of a button, but I must also have the position of the item in the gridview that is being touched. I basically have a gridview that is a d-pad control. So when the user pushed on it i need it to send "go" and when they release i need it to send "stop"

with this below , there is no way to tell when they lift off the button (that i know!).

```
    Grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(c, mThumbIds));
    Grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = what;
            msg.arg1 = position;
            cHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    });
```

but If i use a ontouch listner I cant tell which item in the grid they have selected

```
Grid.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = 255;
                    msg.arg1 = 255;
                    cHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.what = what;
                        msg.arg1 = 55;
                        cHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

your time is greatly appreciated !!

/// well this is what i've been trying to do, i can never get the bounds of the different parts of the gridview. The r.getX etc always returns 0. if i have the id of the resource how can i pull its rectangle ?

```
Grid.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(c);

                    for(int n: mThumbIds){
                        imageView.setImageResource(n);
                        r = imageView.getDrawable().getBounds();
                        if(r.contains((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY()))
                        {
                            Message msg = new Message();
                            msg.what = what;
                            msg.arg1 = n;
                            msg.arg2 = (int)event.getRawY();
                            cHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                            break;
                        }else{
                            Message msg = new Message();
                            msg.what = what;
                            msg.arg1 = r.centerX();
                            msg.arg2 = n;
                            cHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                        }
                    }// end for
                }// end if action up
```

Answer (score 0):

michael , Well You have two choices for such an implementation

- Set onclickListener on each of
  widgets in each grid
  Item(eg.Textview/ImageView)

OR

- [Customize GridView](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927172131/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/09/extending-and-customizing-gridview-with.html)

And you're Done!

Comment: How do i iterate through the gridview and access each item. I keep trying to find the bounds of the imageviews from inside the ontouch listener but it always returns 0 as the x/y etc.

Comment: michael are you opting for Customizing GridView?